# tensorflow/tensorflow-gpu:2.6.0 docker image broken?

Tags: docker, tensorflow

For some time now I am doing object detection on the GPU using tensorflow.
I have the following problem: I am forced to stick with version 2.3.0 because all versions after 2.3.0 fail with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main/python/roldetector/video_rol_detector.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 438, in <module>
    _ll.load_library(_main_dir)
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 154, in load_library
    py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(lib)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/kernels/libtfkernel_sobol_op.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringEPNS_15OpKernelContextEb
```

I know there are more people having this problem but I have not seen a working solution yet.

The most remarkable - almost contradictory - is that docker is supposed to prevent this
kind of problem. I am working on ubuntu 20.04 but I should not need to specify that  because if the docker image is correct then it should not matter what is running on the host for it to work. Right?

Does anyone have a working solution so I can start using the latest version of tensorflow? (All versions after 2.3.0 seem to suffer from the same problem)

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Why Python 3.6 and not 3.7 or even higher?

Comment: Hi Danny,Apparently python 3.6 is delivered with the image. I have to assume that that is the version of python to use as intended by the person who composed the image.

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to work with Python 3.6: e.g. https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.4.3/ and https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/
You could try to update the base image in your DockerFile though

Comment: Hi Danny, I found this thread which states that it has to do with a change in calling convention: https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/385    I downloaded the image again and now it seems to work. Thank you for your reponses.